# Stream Audio to Google Cast Audio from Raspberry Pi

Tags: audio, stream, raspberry-pi, chromecast, google-cast

I'd like to send audio directly from a Raspberry Pi to a Google Cast Audio device.

I'm happy to do this via a fileserver hosted on the Pi (or similar) but no external services can be used- no internet connection is available during operation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Cast SDK, you would need a "sender" application to initiate the launch of your app on a cast device and sending the instructions to that. After that is done, your (html5) application on the cast device can continue the playback on its own. Whenever the application on the cast device is brought down, you would need a sender to restart this process. The platforms supported by Cast SDK are Android, iOS and chrome, so RP is not among the supported platforms. Another issue in your scenario is that any cast device requires internet connectivity; without one, such device will not boot up completely and won't be useful.